# change particle color on interval

Tags: particles

I am learning blender and I would like to simulate a particle system. I have successfully done that with single colored particles. I am not sure how to change the color of the particles in equal interval. For ex, I want the particles to start with red color and after few frames change to green color and then back to red and vice versa for the entire lifetime.

I am not sure of what nodes to play with. Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: Per-particle, or all together?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the change to be frame dependent, as opposed to lifetime dependent, I would suggest using a Value node with `#frame` written as it's input (makes value = current frame at any point), and then using some math to get the correct interval for your needs. Use this as a material for the object you're instancing as a particle.

In the example below, I took the time that the Sine of the frame number is greater than 0.5 (half the time) and used that as a mix factor for a MixRGB with the two colors. This gives particles that alternate between red and green every other frame. You can also use a ColorRamp if you want more control/multiple colors.

[image: FrameColor]

Lastly, this works in both Cycles and EEVEE.